# How can I implement email confirmation in a user model in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't mean sending a confirmation email, I mean checking to make sure they entered the same email twice. I'm using the `has_secure_password` functionality which automatically checks to make sure the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields match up. Just not sure how to do it with the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of the [Confirmation validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#confirmation).